# Does Typescript Async method return a promise?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am just getting up to speed on Async/Await in Typescript.

I am converting existing code like this:

```
getImportanceTypes(): Promise<void> {
        return this.importanceTypeService.list()
            .then(items => {
                this.importanceTypes = items;
            });
}
```

to:

```
async getImportanceTypes(): Promise<void> {
     this.importanceTypes = await this.importanceTypeService.list()
}
```

The question is: Does this really return a promise?  It must, because it compiles successfully, but in my mind, I see the code execution suspending on the await until it completes, then continuing.

The reason I ask is that I have about 10 similiar calls to the above (different type tables) and I would like them to execute in parallel with Promise.all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `async` functions return promises. (In JavaScript and TypeScript both.) `async`/`await` is "just" syntactic sugar for the creation and consumption of promises (but, you know, *really useful* sugar).

The way you've declared that return type is indeed the correct way to do it. [There's been some dissention on that point](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11097), however. :-) There are some who feel that if the function is declared `async`, you should be able to just specify its *resolution* type rather than explicitly mentioning the promise. At present, though, you do use `Promise<x>` rather than just `x`.